# "Prefer X ones over Y ones" vs. "Prefer X over Y ones"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, relative-pronouns

> Inside functions, prefer superlocal variables over local ones and local ones over global ones; outside functions, prefer global **ones** over superglobal ones.

> Inside functions, prefer superlocal variables over local ones and local ones over global ones; outside functions, prefer global over superglobal ones.

The question is very short, but it's not easy to find an answer on Google.

Do we need to use "ones" as shown in the first example? Or it could be omitted as shown in the second one?

Comment: There is no fixed "answer" It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to "delete" the predictably repeated word ***ones*** in your context - and indeed whether to delete the *first* one or the second one *(the first or the second **one**, the first **one** or the second)*. OR both *(the first or the second).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd accept both as meaning the same.

The deletion is an example of [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) in English.  The predictable and repeated word is deleted.  Many (most? all??) other languages allow for similar patterns.  The grammar is not specfic to the word "one", which is why you may not have been able to find an explaination.